# How to get the a text inside a class only if the class is inside a specific header tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, request, cheerio

```
var request = require ('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require ('fs');

request("http://kathmandupost.ekantipur.com/news/2018-08-31/bimstec-summit-multilateral-meet-underway.html", function(error, response, body){

    if(error){
    console.log("Error: "+ error);
}
    console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    var title = $(this).find('h1 .title').text();
    fs.appendFileSync('ekantipur.txt',title);
});
```

I just want to get the text inside a .title class if the class is inside h1 tag. What am I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: * Go to that page in chrome. * hit F-12 (windows/linux only). * Do Ctrl+F (find) and enter `h1 .title` - no results? That means you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code `this` represent the scope of the callback function. Replace `$(this).find('h1 .title')` by `$('h1 .title)`